# AnimationListener method onAnimationRepeat not calling

Tags: android

I am facing issue while implementing AnimationListener

Here, I have implemented AnimationListener and when I started animation on a button click then onAnimationStart() and onAnimationEnd() is being called but onAnimationRepeat() method is not being called.

What I am doing wrong here, please let me know.

Here is my code:

```
    public class AnimationDemo extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    int i = 0;
    String [] messages;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_demo);
        messages = new String[]{
                "India", "India is", "India is Great", "India is Great Country!"
        };
    }

    public void startAnimation(View view){
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sample_animation);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("MY_TAG", "Animation Started!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("MY_TAG", "Animation End!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("MY_TAG", "Repeating...");
            }
        });

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        textView.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <scale
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="0.0"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"
            android:repeatCount="5"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            />
    </set>
```

Comment: does all other function calls like onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd ?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code, basically you did not added animation to your view:

```
public class AnimationDemo extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final android.view.animation.AnimationUtils AnimationUtils = ;
TextView textView;
int i = 0;
String[] messages;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_demo);
    messages = new String[]{
            "India", "India is", "India is Great", "India is Great Country!"
    };

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    startAnimation(textView);
}

public void startAnimation(View view) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sample_animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.d("MY_TAG", "Animation Started!!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.d("MY_TAG", "Animation End!!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            Log.d("MY_TAG", "Repeating...");
        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason why the onAnimationRepeat listener was not triggered.
If you animate something with XML animation definition file in anim folder then onAnimationRepeat listener never triggered.

You have to define your animation with full paramaters programatically.

That's it...